# CSS positioning creates ugly gap between logo and <aside>

Tags: css, layout, seo, css-position

what I try to achieve:

1. fluid 2 columns percentage design
2. logical, seo friendly. Target order from up to down in html source: nav, logo (h1 hided, logo shown instead), article, aside, footer

what I tried is here: http://jsbin.com/bucalezi/1

everything is OK if the browser maximized; however when browser restored down to a smaller scale than 100%, gap between logo and aside seems ugly. 
The reason of gap is:

1. because of my 2nd requirement I put logo in left div (not in aside) so I had to use position:absolute property. I gave margin to aside in order not to collapse with logo.

and this is the point I could come. How can I both achieve my requirements and get rid of ugly view when browser restored down to a smaller scale

thanks
best regards

Comment: waplet's answer is applied here: [http://jsbin.com/vayadoye/1]

Comment: Your markup could have been much cleaner and minimum to achieve what you want. And hiding logo text is not good SEO wise. Instead you should provide text inside h1 for img alt tag.

Comment: @Morven I think you simply say that delete h1, and give alt tag to image. But I want to use h1 also in seo friendly but invisible way. Can you provide me a example link for my aim, thanks

Comment: Use `h1` tag but don't put any text inside it. You can just embed your image inside your H1 and provide the h1 text in alt attribute. `<h1><img src="logo.png" alt="the required text"></h1>` Hiding things is not good SEO wise, people says :)

Comment: oh, really wise, thnx so much Morven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with floats...
Main content

```
float:left;
```

Aside and logo

```
float:right;
```

, with width specified

http://jsfiddle.net/RyR8n/embedded/result/

Updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/RyR8n/3/embedded/result/